# Take list of fields and put them into one record in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, flat-file

I'm relatively new to SSIS, and I'm not sure how to attack the following.  I've a table with the following:

```
AcctNo   FieldName  Value
1        Name       Bill

1        Address    111 Circle Drive   

1        State      FL

2        Name       Sue

2        Address    123 Apple Road

3        Name       Donald

3        State      TX
```

I'd like to read through the flat file with SSIS and collapse it down into a single record in a table each time the account number changes;  but not write it until all the data for a particular account has been read.  To make it a little more complex, not every record has complete data in it.  (As you can see above Acct 2 is missing the State, Acct 3 is missing the State.)  Appreciate any input anyone has.  Cheers--

Comment: Have you looked at the `PIVOT` Transformation ?

Comment: Yep, google and learn about the PIVOT transformation.

Comment: I have to say PIVOT in SSIS is a bit more complicated than it needs to be, you can import in sql server staging table and use PIVOT syntax to do it in sql server, it is a bit simpler in t-sql as compare to SSIS PIVOT transformation.

Comment: Well, the PIVOT suggestion worked, though I've run into another issue.  It looks like there can be multiple entries of the FieldName based on date last updated.  Is there some way to force the pivot to create a new record based on the date and still group it by the account no?

Comment: Perhaps include Last Update date as another key? You could then group data by AcctNo/Last Update Date